# Align card text next to image

Tags: css

I've dived last weeks a bit more into react.js with Gatsby and Prismic. I've created blog cards which I display using flex: wrap (Check the image) , now I want to display my blog cards horizontal.

[image: Attached Image]

If I do nowrap:

[image: Attached Image]

MY CODE:

Cardlist.js:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <div className="cardslist">{children}</div>

  {/* --- STYLES --- */}
  <style jsx>{`
    .cardslist {
      text-align: center;

    }

    @from-width desktop {
      .cardslist {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap
      }
    }
  `}</style>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Use `nowrap` instead?

Comment: If I do nowrap , post building next to eachother, I want on desktop one post with the image left and the text right, and then under it the next post and so on.

Comment: Check the image above ive uploaded it.

Comment: I want to have a list style

Comment: Is there any code that you can add to the question?

Comment: <React.Fragment>
      <div className="cardslist">{children}</div>

      {/* --- STYLES --- */}
      <style jsx>{`
        .cardslist {
          text-align: center;

        }

        @from-width desktop {
          .cardslist {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap
          }
        }
      `}</style>
    </React.Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: But how do I align the text to the right? Check my code above, ive updated my question

Comment: Here I made it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/y5a8v42m/3/. You can take inspiration from that code and make changes to yours! :)